# Having trouble creating my own adapter

Tags: list, adapter, listadapter

So I'm going along with a lynda.com video on creating a custom list layout. I have gone along with the video but I am not able to change my constructor in order to change the code so it is an array of strings. In both places where I have written MyAdapter, there is a red squiggle below and the top one tells me MyAdapter cannot be resolved to a type. Please assist.

```
        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter<String>(CustomList2Activity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textView1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.companies2)));


        private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

            public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                    int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
                super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are declaring the MyAdapter class in the right place. Make sure you're not declaring it within a function. Also, go to the source menu (assuming you're using eclipse) and press "organize imports" to make sure your imports are right.